# Why these specific "things that fly" in "Kite-Flying"?

Tags: poetry, symbolism, wording-choice, rose-under-fire, elizabeth-wein

Rose Justice, the main character of *Rose Under Fire*, writes several poems that appear in various places in the book. This is the second verse of [*Kite-Flying*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rose_Under_Fire/DKA4yDSB5JEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=KITE_FLYING%20(by%20Rose%20Justice)):

> Hope waits stubbornly,
> watching the sky
> for turmoil, feeding on
> things that fly:
> **crows, ashes, newspapers,
>
> dry leaves in flight**
> all suggest wind
> that could lift a kite.
> <sub>In the section starting "April 30, 1945/Paris"</sub>

Is there some symbolic significance to the specific items listed? I highly doubt they are random. This poem comes up twice in the book, both important times. But I'm unsure what connection "crows, ashes, newspapers" and "dry leaves in flight" have to each other. Or how they're connected hope and what it takes to sustain hope (a major theme of the poem).

Why these specific "things that fly" in "Kite-Flying"?

Comment: Adding as a comment, as I have no evidence or author's commentary to back this up. I think these 4 things have downbeat, somewhat negative connotations. Crows aren't pretty songbirds but caw and are associated with ill omens (or is that more ravens?) Ashes are rubbish, as are newspapers - flying in wind they would be discarded loose sheets, not fresh clean papers. Dry leaves are dead, fallen from trees. All these can be seen as hopeLESS things, but the poem says that they still fly, so a kite (which is a more hopeful image) could fly too.

Comment: An answer backed up by the text without author comments is fine! Books and their meanings do not depend on authorial intent.